# CSS Speech bubble arrow not responsivne

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create speech bubbles like below using **Viewport Sized Typography**
[image]

**Everything works. It's not ideal but works... only problem is that the "arrow" wont stay at its place when resizing window it moves either inside or outside of bubble after resize**

Here is my code so far:

```css
.speechBubble {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3vw yellow;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 58px;
  -moz-border-radius: 58px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0px 100px 0px 100px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
  max-width: 30vw;
}

.speechBubble:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3vw 11.3vw 2vw 0;
  border-color: transparent #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 4.5vw;
  top: -30px;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(53deg);
}

.speechBubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3vw 11.3vw 2vw 0;
  border-color: transparent #000000;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 5vw;
  top: -25px;
  transform: rotate(53deg);
  display: block;
}

.speechBubbleContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 30px;
  line-height: 3.7vw;
  font-size: 3.7vw;
  max-width: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="speechBubble">
  <div class="speechBubbleContent">Some realy really really long text</div>
</div>
```